# Int object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

ok so I have a program that has four different cities and each city has a distance. The program will ask the user what cities they would like to calculate and it will return the distance between the two cities in miles. Now I have a working loop that will ask the user to input city 1 and then city 2, once done the program will return the distance between the two cities. However I then attempted to do the same thing but ask the user to choose three different cities, and then return the distance between the three cities. The code is literally the same except one returns "int object is not subscriptable"

I'll paste first the code that works for looping the question twice and outputting the text. I'll then paste the one where I've altered it to loop three times and attempt to output the distance of the three cities in miles.

My cities and distances code

```
cities=["Coventry", "Birmingham", "Wolverhampton", "Leicester"]
distances=[
    [0,25,33,24],
    [25,0,17,42],
    [33,17,0,54],
    [24,42,54,0]]
```

Working two cities code

```
def distancestwo():
    choices=[0,1] 
    for j in range(2): #This will loop twice, hence giving the option for two cities. More could be added!
        for i in range(len(cities)):
            p.write ("%d : %s\n" %(i, cities[i]))
        p.write("\nEnter city number %d: \n"%(j+1))
        choices[j]=p.nextInt()

    p.write("\n") #Leaves a line for the output of the distance



    p.write("The distance between %s and %s is \n%d miles!\n"\
         % (cities[choices[0]], cities [choices[1]],distances [choices[0]] [choices[1]]))
```

This one however return the in object is not subscriptable

```
def distancesthree():
    choices=[0,1,2] 
    for j in range(3): #This will loop three times 
        for i in range(len(cities)):
            p.write ("%d : %s\n" %(i, cities[i]))
        p.write("\nEnter city number %d: \n"%(j+1))
        choices[j]=p.nextInt()

    p.write("\n") #Leaves a line for the output of the distance



    p.write("The distance between %s ,%s and %s is \n %d miles!\n"\
             % (cities[choices[0]], cities [choices[1]], cities [choices[2]],distances [choices[0]] [choices[1]] [choices[2]]))
```

Comment: What's `cities`? Where is it defined?

Comment: What is `p` and why are you calling `p.nextInt()`?

Comment: What does "the distance between three cities" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to subscript a list of lists with three indices:

```
distances[choices[0]][choices[1]][choices[2]]
```

where you probably wanted something like

```
distances[choices[0]][choices[1]] + distances[choices[1][choices[2]]
```

Next time, give the precise error message you get.

Comment: I don't think that would work mate, if you look at the working code that calculates the distance between two cities it works absolutely fine, which is  p.write("The distance between %s and %s is \n%d miles!\n"\
         % (cities[choices[0]], cities [choices[1]],distances [choices[0]] [choices[1]]))

Comment: I've only added to that code an extra %s as it needs to return a third city as a string value, and then added [choices[1]] as there is one more city it needs to take into account when returning the distance. So concidering I have a working two city calculation code, I don't see what's made all the difference adding a bit onto the end :/

Comment: @Daniel you don't have any idea _how_ your code for two cities works, do you? See my answer for an explanation for the error. And as I also stated in my post, asking for a _distance_ between three points doesn't make sense in the first place...

Comment: You was right, and I never clearly thought about what I was asking. But needless to say as long as I change what the question to what is was supposed to be "Write a program which will enable the user to enter a sequence of cities and give the total distance travelled when the cities are visited in that order." it will make a little more sense :)

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because of this part:

```
distances [choices[0]] [choices[1]] [choices[2]]
```

Your code for 2 cities works because `distances` is a list of lists containing the distances between cities, so doing `distances[choices[0]][choices[1]]` first selects the distance list for the first chosen city and then selects the entry for the second city:

```
dist_list = distances[choices[0]] #list of distances
distance_in_miles = dist_list[choices[1]]  #entry for the selected city
```

So in your new code, you try to do this:

```
result = distance_in_miles[choices[2]]
```

Which of course doesn't work as the thing you're trying to index is a number and not a list or dictionary etc.

Furthermore, what you're trying to do doesn't even begin to make sense as there is no such thing as a *distance* between *three* points. You could calculate the distance from city1 to city2 to city3 or any permutation of this, or search for the shortest path visiting these three cities, but just asking for a "distance" doesn't make any sense.